# Having trouble loading package "ndtv" in R

Tags: r

I am a very new user to R. I'm having trouble loading a specific package, `ndtv` while using R version 3.3.3, and I'm not sure how to fix it. The output is shown below. I have also included the output for installing `openssl`. I would greatly appreciate any guidance. Thank you!

```
 install.packages("ndtv")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.3/ndtv_0.10.0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1038395 bytes (1014 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 1014 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/2k/v2d50mgs4p7fcgms0t1cmzfr0000gq/T//RtmpSbDxIq/downloaded_packages
> library(ndtv)
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘openssl’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ndtv’

> install.packages("openssl")

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
        binary source needs_compilation
openssl  0.9.9  1.0.1              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?
y/n: y
installing the source package ‘openssl’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/openssl_1.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1194261 bytes (1.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.1 MB

* installing *source* package ‘openssl’ ...
** package ‘openssl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Homebrew 1.5.2
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision d46a; last commit 2018-02-02)
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because openssl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: openssl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libssl_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: openssl@1.1 (Mac OSX)
If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘openssl’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/openssl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/2k/v2d50mgs4p7fcgms0t1cmzfr0000gq/T/RtmpOf01bl/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: What happens when you try `install.packages("openssl")`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I seem to receive an error when I attempt to install openssl. The full output is too long to include, but I think this is the specific error:

Comment: `ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘openssl’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/openssl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status`

Comment: The output is too long to include in a comment, but it is perfectly appropriate to edit your question and add it there. You will not get `ndtv` installed without this, so your problem is with `openssl`, not `ndtv`.

Comment: I see, thank you! The full output is included in edits now.

Comment: That error seems fairly self-describing. Can you do `brew install openssl@1.1` (shell terminal, not R), as the error message implies.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks very much for your help and patience!